# GSM SSL Handshake ssl.py

Tags: python, ssl, gsm

I am doing an SSL connection via a Python script. When I'm on a high speed connection it is successful, but when using a slow GSM connection I get an error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 831, in do_handshake
  self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

I am using SIM800L for GSM connectivity on a Linux (debian) system.
I can do the SSL connection via 'openssl s_client -connect ...' in the terminal, therefore I am thinking there's some limit set in ssl.py (seems to always take around 60sec before above error).

Is there a limit ~60sec on above handshake? If so, how can this be increased?

### EDIT WITH MORE DETAILS:

### **ON WIFI**

Openssl connects within some seconds. Python script successful.

> name@name:~ $ openssl s_client -connect
> string-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883 -tls1_2 -CAfile
> /cert/AmazonRootCA1.pem -cert /cert/certificate.pem.key -key
> /cert/private.pem.key

```
CONNECTED(00000003) 

depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1 

verify return:1 

depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon 

verify return:1 

depth=0 CN = *.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 

verify return:1 

--- 

Certificate chain 

0 s:CN = *.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 

   i:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon 

1 s:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon 

   i:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1 

2 s:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1 

   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2 

3 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2 

   i:C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority 

--- 

Server certificate 

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 

MI....3h9VY= 

-----END CERTIFICATE----- 

subject=CN = *.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 

  

issuer=C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon 

  

--- 

No client certificate CA names sent 

Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign 

Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1 

Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224 

Peer signing digest: SHA256 

Peer signature type: RSA 

Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits 

--- 

SSL handshake has read 5400 bytes and written 1514 bytes 

Verification: OK 

--- 

New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 

Server public key is 2048 bit 

Secure Renegotiation IS supported 

Compression: NONE 

Expansion: NONE 

No ALPN negotiated 

SSL-Session: 

    Protocol  : TLSv1.2 

    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 

    Session-ID: 51...9 

    Session-ID-ctx:  

    Master-Key: 9...F 

    PSK identity: None 

    PSK identity hint: None 

    SRP username: None 

    Start Time: 1598423483 

    Timeout   : 7200 (sec) 

    Verify return code: 0 (ok) 

    Extended master secret: yes 

---
```

> name@name:~ $ sudo python /application/awsiotpub.py

```
Loaded MQTT configuration information. 

Endpoint URL: string-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 

Root Cert: /cert/AmazonRootCA1.pem 

Device Cert: /cert/certificate.pem.key 

Private Key: /cert/private.pem.key 

Connecting to AWS IoT Broker... 

ssl.py : SSLSocket.__init__ if connected 

ssl.py : SSLSocket.__init__ if connected, self._sslobj = :  

<_ssl._SSLSocket object at 0xb62480c0> 

ssl.py - do_handshake() 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected START 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected DONE 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - try do_handshake() START 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - try do_handshake() DONE 

Connected with status: 0 

True 

Publishing... 

Published: 123
```

### ON GSM

Openssl successfully connects after **67sec**. Python script fails on ssl.py handshake after ~60sec.

> name@name:~ $ openssl s_client -connect
> string-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883 -tls1_2 -CAfile
> /cert/AmazonRootCA1.pem -cert /cert/certificate.pem.key -key
> /cert/private.pem.key

```
CONNECTED(00000003) 
.....
```

> name@name:~ $ sudo python /application/awsiotpub.py

```
Loaded MQTT configuration information. 

Endpoint URL: string-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 

Root Cert: /cert/AmazonRootCA1.pem 

Device Cert: /cert/certificate.pem.key 

Private Key: /cert/private.pem.key 

Connecting to AWS IoT Broker... 

ssl.py : SSLSocket.__init__ if connected 

ssl.py : SSLSocket.__init__ if connected, self._sslobj = :  

<_ssl._SSLSocket object at 0xb62480c0> 

ssl.py - do_handshake() 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected START 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected DONE 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - try do_handshake() START 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - finally settimeout START 

ssl.py - do_handshake() - finally settimeout DONE 

Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "awsiotpub.py", line 40, in <module> 

   Client.connect(mqtt_url, port = 8883, keepalive=240) 

File "../paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect 

   Return self.reconnect() 

File "../paho/mqtt/client.py" line 1100, in reconnect 

   Sock.do_handshake() 

File "/user/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 839, in do_handshake 

   Self._sslobj.do_handshake() 

   Soket.error: [Errno 0] Error
```

**ssl.py extract of handshake**

```
.
.
.
    def do_handshake(self, block=False):
        """Perform a TLS/SSL handshake."""
        print("ssl.py - do_handshake()")
        print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected START")
        self._check_connected()
        print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - _check_connected DONE")
        timeout = self.gettimeout()
        try:
            if timeout == 0.0 and block:
                print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - if timeout == 0.0")
                self.settimeout(None)
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - try do_handshake() START")
            self._sslobj.do_handshake()
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - try do_handshake() DONE")
        finally:
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - finally settimeout START")
            self.settimeout(timeout)
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - finally settimeout DONE")

        if self.context.check_hostname:
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - context.check_hostname START")
            if not self.server_hostname:
                print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - context.check_hostname - if not server_hostname")
                raise ValueError("check_hostname needs server_hostname "
                                 "argument")
            match_hostname(self.getpeercert(), self.server_hostname)
            print("ssl.py - do_handshake() - context.check_hostname DONE")
.
.
.
```

Comment: There are not enough details to answer this question. There is no way to reproduce the problem and you don't even show a useful error description but only that "something" happens in SSL `do_handshake`. But as for timeouts - see [this part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply! I have provided more details.
timeout inside ssl.py : do_handshake is 240sec, but it stops and throw the error after ~60sec.

Comment: *"timeout inside ssl.py : do_handshake is 240sec"* - where do you see this? I cannot see that you print out the timeout you get from `gettimeout` somewhere nor do I see that you explicitly set one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes sorry, in above you dont see it. In the python script I specify 240s as timeout, and in ssl.py I've tried "print(timeout)" which prints 240.
Not sure if this timeout is for the connect part, and not the handshake?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I've tried with a simple server which completes the handshake after 80 seconds. I got in my python client no timeout, i.e. the handshake completed after 80 sec. If I've used `settimeout` to a shorter value it would follow this setting and fault with 'The handshake operation timed out'. Tried with python 2.7.13 and 3.7.3.